# Про клиент-серверное взаимодействие

Tags: сервер

Когда мы входим в систему, т.е. вбиваем логин, пароль и жмем кнопку войти, запрос отправляется методом пост. Мой вопрос: как сервер понимает, что пользователь залогин? И еще вопрос: этот запрос отправляется тоже в URL адресе, как и при методе get?

Comment: 1) Как разработчик сервера захочет сделать, так и понимает. 2) Без разницы какой URL

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы отправляете логин и пароль, сервер придумывает для вас уникальную последовательность символов, которую вам сообщает

Например, этоВасяСТретьегоПодъездаКоторыйПравильноУказалПарольВ9Часов04Минуты

Такая последовательность называется `токен` и он имеет некоторый срок жизни

В следующих get запросах вы указываете этот токен в теле запроса.

Когда сервер видит этот токен, он понимает, да да, я тебя помню, ты правильно ввёл пароль, поэтому я не буду пока что спрашивать у тебя пароль ещё раз